# build bash string containing a variable value surrounded with single quotes

Tags: string, bash, variables, quote

I'm having a nightmare from what should be the most trivial of tasks.

My final goal is issue the following command from a bash script:
`sqlite3 my_db.db '.read my_file.sql'`

There are two catches here:
1. The single-quotes are obligatory, and can't be replaced by, say, double-quotes
2. `my_file.sql` is a variable known only at run-time.

So what I need is a way to have bash build a string that on one hand contains a variable value, while on the other hand that value should be surrounded by single quotes.

I would also much prefer a solution not relying on additional tools like AWK, Perl or the like. Maybe sed if it's really necessary.

Thanks.

---

Thanks Jonathan and Nelson.

I tried all three suggestions, but they all failed.
For simplicity I reduced the problem to the following:

1. I wrote the following script (tst.sh):
   `#!/bin/bash`
   `file=/tmp/1`
   `ls "'"$file"'"`
   `ls \'$file\'`
   `ls "'$file'"`
2. Then I isuues the following commands:
   `$ touch /tmp/1`
   `$ ls '/tmp/1'`
   `/tmp/1`
   `$ ./tst.sh`
   `'/tmp/1': No such file or directory`
   `'/tmp/1': No such file or directory`
   `'/tmp/1': No such file or directory`

It seems the quotes were indeed added, but the resulting command  was not the same as when entered manually.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's the reason for single quotes being obligatory?  Is that supposed to be one argument in single quotes or two arguments, one starting with a single quote and the other ending with a single quote.

Answer (score 1):

Single-quotes are *not* obligatory. All of the following commands run sqlite3 with exactly the same arguments:

```
sqlite3 my_db.db '.read my_file.sql'
sqlite3 my_db.db ".read my_file.sql"
sqlite3 my_db.db .read\ my_file.sql
sqlfile="my_file.sql"
sqlite3 my_db.db ".read $sqlfile"
```

In all cases, the quotes (/escape) are parsed *and removed* before the arguments are passed to sqlite3. This is what you want. You want sqlite3 to get two arguments: `my_db.db` and `.read my_file.sql`. You do *not* want sqlite3 to see the quotes around the command -- that would be the equivalent of:

```
$ sqlite3 my_db.db
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> '.read my_file.sql'
   ...>
```

...which, as you can see, just confuses sqlite3.

BTW, this is the same as the problem in your ls examples: you're passing single-quotes as part of the argument to ls, so it's looking for a file with single-quotes in the name and not finding it. You *want* the shell to remove the quotes rather than pass them to the command as part of an argument.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - That's important information I was not aware of. My question though, was broader then an sqlite3 syntax, as can be seen in the subject. I believe my last answer will be helpful for others in many other cases.

Comment: @user1860085: take a deep breath and understand what several commenters here have repeatedly tried to explain: you are solving the wrong problem, and you need to understand the shell's quoting mechanisms.

Comment: And +1 for this lucid answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
VAR=my_file.sql
VAR2="'.read $VAR'"
sqlite3 my_db.db $VAR2
```

Comment: Or without variables `sqlite3 my_db.db "'.read my_file.sql'"` but I doubt this is actually the solution, although that's what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you say you want to do (getting single quotes to the program), but it uses double quotes:

```
sqlite3 my_db.db "'".read" "my_file.sql"'"
```

Avoiding double quotes, you can write:

```
sqlite3 my_db.db \'.read\ my_file.sql\'
```

For both of these, the second argument will be seen by `sqlite3` as a string containing:

```
'.read my_file.sql'
```

If the file name is in a variable (`file=my_file.sql`), then:

```
sqlite3 my_db.db "'".read" "$file"'"
sqlite3 my_db.db \'.read\ $file\'
```

These notations are vulnerable to confusion if the file name contains spaces.

However, I don't think that's likely to be what you really want.  The proscription on double quotes is puzzling, and the requirement for single quotes is likewise puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

user1860085, if you check out documentation for **sqlite3** command and you will know how shell treats quotes and white spaces, you will probably come to conclusion that you want double quotes for your case.

but if you really want single quotes, here is solution:

```
eval sqlite3 my_db.db \'.read $VARIABLE\'
```

which in the fly will change to:

```
sqlite3 my_db.db '.read my_file.sql'
```

But I don't see why you could want it...

Answer (score -2):

OK, problem solved !!

All that was missing is adding a little 'eval' command before the line.
So, in the simple example script I gave, changing:
`ls "'$file'"` to:
`eval ls "'$file'"`
did the job.

Thanks to all replyers :-)

Comment: Aack, no! eval's main purpose is to create incomprehensible bugs. It can be used safely if you know *exactly* what you're doing, but this is not one of those cases.

Comment: lol, sorry, no offense intended ;-)   Can you detail about the problematic nature of eval you mentioned, and how it would compromise my solution (which seems to be working..) ?

Comment: It shows how to get rid of two layers of quote marks, but the end result is exacly equivalent to `ls "$file"`.

Comment: it's not equivalent to ls "$file" in the case where the quote is required. for example in my original example it works, when <.read $file> fails.

Comment: What you're doing here is adding single-quotes around the command, and then using `eval` to remove them. Seriously, that's the only thing `eval` is doing here. If it does anything else, it will be something bad. In this particular case, `eval` will only cause trouble if the filename contains single-quotes (in which case sqlite3 will have trouble anyway), but you're better off avoiding the problem in the first place. What makes you think you need single-quotes anyway? I'm pretty sure any problem you're having with `sqlite3 my_db.db ".read $file"` is not due to the lack of single-quotes.

Comment: You're right - double-quotes didn't work for another reason, and now I found that it does. this indeed makes the use of eval unnecessary. Thank you and all contributers for your help !